# How to run mysql database independently and copy its folder to another path

Tags: python, mysql

I am writting a gui program in python using PYQt6 library. I have a database for my program in mysql. so i want the mysql database as a folder of my project when the software has been installed regardeless of the xampp server. when the program starts the mysql server should be started and when the program is closed the server should be stopped.The main quesiton is this that I dont' want the xampp server and want to execute mysql independently. Please Help me if you know???

I tried alot but could not get the result I wanted

Comment: An embedded database, like sqlite seems to be better suited for your requirements as those are file based and do not require a service to run, like mysql.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to include a MySQL database within your PyQt6 GUI program and manage the MySQL server independently without relying on XAMPP, you can consider using the MySQL Connector/Python library. Here's a general outline of the steps involved:

1. Install the MySQL Connector/Python library:

   - Install the MySQL Connector/Python library by running the following command in your terminal:

     ```
     pip install mysql-connector-python
     ```
2. Create a MySQL database file:

   - Instead of running a separate MySQL server, you can utilize a local MySQL database file within your project directory.
   - Create a new MySQL database file (e.g., `mydatabase.db`) using the MySQL Connector/Python library. This file will contain the database schema and data.
   - You can execute SQL commands to create tables, insert data, and perform other database operations using the library.
3. Start the MySQL server:

   - To start the MySQL server when your program starts, you can execute the appropriate command within your Python code.
   - Use the `subprocess` module to run the MySQL server command. The exact command depends on your operating system and the MySQL distribution you're using.
   - Here's an example of starting the MySQL server using the `subprocess` module on Windows:

     ```py
     import subprocess

     def start_mysql_server():
         subprocess.run(["mysqld", "--console"], check=True)

     # Call the start_mysql_server() function when your program starts.
     ```
4. Connect to the MySQL database:

   - Use the MySQL Connector/Python library to establish a connection to the MySQL database file (`mydatabase.db`) within your PyQt6 application.
   - You'll need to provide the appropriate connection details, such as the host, port, username, password, and database name.
   - Here's a basic example of connecting to the MySQL database:

     ```py
     import mysql.connector

     # Connect to the MySQL database
     connection = mysql.connector.connect(
         host="localhost",
         port=3306,
         user="root",
         password="your_password",
         database="mydatabase.db"
     )

     # Create a cursor to execute SQL queries
     cursor = connection.cursor()

     # Execute SQL queries and interact with the database

     # Close the cursor and connection when finished
     cursor.close()
     connection.close()
     ```
5. Stop the MySQL server:

   - To stop the MySQL server when your program closes, you can execute the appropriate command within your Python code, similar to starting the server.
   - Use the `subprocess` module to run the command to stop the MySQL server.
   - Here's an example of stopping the MySQL server using the `subprocess` module on Windows:

     ```py
     def stop_mysql_server():
         subprocess.run(["mysqladmin", "-u", "root", "-p", "shutdown"])

     # Call the stop_mysql_server() function when your program closes.
     ```

By following these steps, you can include a MySQL database within your PyQt6 GUI program and manage the MySQL server independently without relying on XAMPP. Remember to handle error cases, manage connections properly, and ensure that the necessary MySQL server binaries are available on the system where the program is running.

Comment: GenAI generated answers are not allowed in general and thus one is incorrect on so many levels.